# Why Unity keep showing Loading assembly failed: error

Tags: unity-game-engine, dllimport

I'm using Unity2020.1.17f1 with .NET 4.x API compatiblitiy.

I had tried to use System.Drawing.imaging to use bitmap.

Because Unity's intrinsic .NET 4.x doesn't support System.Drawing.imaging, I imported System.Drawing.dll from C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0 to Unity Project Folder\Assets\Plugins.

There were no problem during editing code and compiling, but as soon as I try to run Unity Project, It keeps showing Loading assembly failed: "Assets/Plugins/System.Drawing.dll" Error without any description.

What should I do? And Is there any other way to use System.Drawing.Imaging from intrinsic Unity?

Comment: [Unity does not support the System.Drawing library and it is not guaranteed to work on all platforms.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/overview-of-dot-net-in-unity.html) To process bitmaps in unity, use Texture2D and ImageConversion classes.

Comment: My purpose is load bitmap image from local storage and change it texture2D to wrap object. Can ImageConversion Class convert bmp to texture2D?

Comment: It can load png and jpg

Comment: @shingo that's why I had googled how to import System.Drawing.Imaging namespace. Anyway, I found private namespace that can convert bmp to texture2D, and my project work well now.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like there is an important file missing that Unity needs to run the project.

There are some ways you can go about this:

1. Check if this happens in a blank project or if this happens in other projects as well
2. Completely uninstall and reinstall Unity
3. Change Unity Version and try the steps above again

I would suggest you try out the steps 1 and 2. And if nothing helps I would try step 3.